# Google+ Sign-on Android app : Will all Android users have a Google+ account?

Tags: android, google-plus

I am in the middle of working on Android app, and for the user registration bit, I've been reading how they recommend developers to make use of Google+ sign-on integration.

However, I was wondering, will there be any possibility of Android users not having a Google+ account? Will a Google+ account automatically be created for anyone who registered their Android devices with a valid Gmail account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play requires that users have a Google account to install apps and the [new Google+ Sign-In flow](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#all-users) works for all Google accounts regardless of them being upgraded to Google+ or not.

Comment: have you seen this work though? I am currently implementing sign in using the google+ examples but it will ask for a g+ profile creation when you do not have it yet. It seems that the libraries are not up-to-date with the documentation and developers are restricted to using GoogleAuthUtil instead...

Comment: @Nebula added a comment to your question.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is entirely possible for a user to not have a Google+ account. An account does not get automatically created for you. When you first get the device you get prompted to sign-up but that does not mean they will as they can skip that and do it at a later time

Answer (score 1):

A Google+ account is not required for someone to use an Android device. Most people who use them will have one, but there will be some who do not. If you make an app with G+ sign in, add some other way to sign in as well. However, Google is pushing this hard and is even requiring a G+ account to comment on YouTube Videos. See this like for more info: http://readwrite.com/2014/01/10/google-plus-inescapable#awesm=~oya6fZfWHOVNbo

Answer (score 0):

Some users' accounts may not be allowed to have Google+ accounts. For example if the account is a work account, this can be due to the administrator disabling Google+ for their account. In this case the user would receive the message:

> "Google+ is unavailable for your account. Please contact your domain
>   administrator to see if Google+ can be enabled for your account."

[Here is some tangential information](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1631746?hl=en) about how one would go about enabling the Google+ account.